# Sonar violation in Java on DoubleValue.equals(AnotherDoubleValue) - Why?

Tags: java, sonarqube, java-11

I have a piece of code in Java where -

```
public boolean method1(Double d1, Double d2) {

  if (d1.equals(d2)) {

    //Some logic
    return bool;

}
```

The statement d1.equals(d2) has a sonar violation which says that "Equality tests should not be made with floating point values." Link : https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1244

In the explanation it talks about where using a == or === matters but since I'm using a equals method, why does it still show this up as a sonar violation?

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with `==` versus `equals`, and everything to do with how both `double` and `Double` (and `float` and `Float`) values are very difficult to ensure that they are exactly, 100% equal -- and not, say, different by 0.0000000000001.

Sonar is recommending that you do something like, say, `Math.abs(d1 - d2) < 0.0000001`.

Answer (score -3):

I think the sonar violation is showing up, because you are invoking the **equals** method on two objects, which are most likely not the same.

However the **Double** class has solved this problem, by overwriting the **equals** method and just checking weather the two numbers contained in the object are equal.
I just checked that in Java, just to be safe that it works. You can thus just ignore the warning.

Hope this helps.
Kind regards,
403